# clarification regarding an if statement in ksh

Tags: unix, if-statement, ksh

Im quite new to ksh scripting, please bear with me, if this is too obvious

What does this mean in ksh? Is this also a way to write an if condition?

```
[[ -n $MSRV_SGL ]] && {
    msrv_ps || return 1
}
```

msrv_ps is a function

How does this read? `if the length of string $MSRV_SGL is non zero....`?

I havent come across such expressions in any online examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is telling you: if var length is not zero, execute function and return 1 if it's exit code is not zero.

It can be constructed as:

```
if [[ -n $MSRV_SGL ]];then
   if  ! msrv_ps;then 
      return 1
   fi 
fi
```

> { list; }
>                 list is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon. 
>   This is known as a group command.
>                 The return status is the exit status of list.  Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and ), { and } are reserved words  and 
>   must  occur  where  a
>                 reserved  word  is  permitted  to  be recognized.  Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from list by
>   whitespace or another
>                 shell metacharacter.

Comment: `msrv_ps || return 1` does not mean `msrv_ps; return 1`. Should be `if ! msrv_ps; then return 1; fi`.

Comment: You're abolutely right, i was thinking on `&&` operator :) . Thanks @whjm

Comment: Thank you.. that clarified things :)